# DependencyProperty for UserControl with DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, datacontext, dependency-properties

I have a ListBox where I'm using a UserControl as DataTemplate. My UserControl has a ViewModel. I have a DependencyProperty in my UserControl so that I can bind item from my ListBox to my UserControl.

It does not work unless I do not set any DataContext to my UserControl.

How can I use DP and custom DataContext in my UC ?

My ListBox:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListItems, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <local:MyCustomUC MyObject="{Binding Path=.}"/>
             </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

My UserControl XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControlDataTemplate.MyCustomUC"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FromViewModel}" />
        <Button Content="{Binding ElementName=MyObject, Path=FromParent}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

My UserControl CS:

```
       public MyClass MyObject
        {
            get { return (MyClass)GetValue(MyObjectProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(MyObjectProperty, value);
            }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyObjectProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyObject", typeof(MyClass), typeof(MyCustomUC), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public MyCustomUC()
        {
           InitializeComponent();

           this.DataContext = new MyCustomUCViewModel();
        }

My ViewModel:

    public class MyCustomUCViewModel : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public String FromViewModel { get; set; }

        public MyCustomUCViewModel()
        {
            this.FromViewModel = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
        ...
     }
```

Item class in ItemSource from ListBox:

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public String FromParent { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are setting the DataContext in the MyCustomUC()
instead you can set DataContext like this

```
<vm:YourViewModel x:Name="VModel" IfPropertToSet="{BindingFromExistingDC}"/>  

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListItems, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <local:MyCustomUC MyObject="{Binding Path=.}" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=VModel}" />
             </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

you need to include the namespace

```
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:YourViewModelPath"
```

Comment: but the question is why the binding engine uses DataContext set in UserControl instead of the DataContext of the containing control (in this case generated by the ListBox)? why setting the DataContext in XAML works differently than in code?